# how to make neural network function faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I have this function for a neural network and it's the function to calculate the next layer from a list of inputs and a list of weights. Is there any way to make this faster or more efficient?
the arguments inp is the input, weights are the weights, layerlength is the length of the next layer and rounds is just the length to round the output to.

```
def output(inp,weights,layerlength,rounds):
    layer=[]
    count=0
    lappend=layer.append
    for a in range(layerlength):
        total=0
        for b in range(len(inp)):  
            total+=inp[b]*weights[count]
            count+=1
        lappend(round(total,rounds))
    return layer
```

Comment: run it on a high-end GPU? I think you will need CUDA python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, try not to use `for` loop constructs in Python. They are extremely slow. Use Matrix operations programmed with `numpy` instead, then the loops will run under the hood in C++ instead (50 to 100 times faster). 
You can easily reformulate your above piece of code without any Python for loops by defining your `layer` and `inp` vectors and your `weights` matrix all as `numpy.array()` and then perform matrix multiplication on them.

EDIT: 
I hope I am not helping you cheat on your homework here ;)

```
import numpy as np
# 10 dimensional input
inpt = np.arange(10)
# 20 neurons in the first (fully connected) layer
weights = np.random.rand(10, 20)
# mat_mul: to calculate the input to the non-linearity of the first layer
# you need to multiply each input dimension with all the weights assigned to a specific neuron of the first layer
# and then sum them up, and this for all the neurons in that layer
# you can do all of that in this single Matrix multiplication
layer = np.matmul(inpt, weights)
print(inpt.shape)
print()
print(weights.shape)
print()
print(layer.shape)
```

Comment: thanks but could you tell me how exactly you would do that? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming you're computing the activations of one layer.

Make sure you use linear algebra libraries like Numpy (or Tensorflow, PyTorch, etc). These will make sure your computations run much more efficient on the CPU (or GPU). Typically using `for` loops give a lot of computational overhead.

For example, in [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) you can write your feedforward pass for one layer as:

```
output = inp.dot(weights)
```

`inp` is here your `n` by `m` input matrix, `weights` is your `m` by `k` weight matrix. `output` will then be a `n` by `k` matrix of your forward step activations.

Comment: I see. So I should use numpy.array instead of a list? And if so, how will I have to change the rest of the code where I use the list?

Comment: also, I don't understand what you mean by n by m matrix, m by k matrix, and n by k matrix. are there any websites I should look at?

Comment: [This is a very brief introduction to what a matrix is](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-introduction.html).

If you are not familiar with matrices I would suggest taking an online course on linear algebra such as the one on [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra)

Comment: and how exactly would you implement it? Be cause inp and weights have different lengths.